# View Models Two Way Comminication

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm developing a reusable WPF control "R" that has its own view model "VM_R".
I have a WPF main window "Main" that uses control R and it has its own view model as well "VM_Main".

My question:
I want VM_Main and VM_R to communicate in the following manner:

VM_Main send a request to VM_R to evaluate something and send the result back to VM_Main.

I have considered the following options:

1. Instantiate VM_R in VM_Main. This will create a coupling
   concerns.
2. I can use MVVM Light Messenger. However I don't want to have two Register Calls and two Sends calls.

Thank you

Comment: No, that's what **DepenencyProperty** (s) are for

Comment: Why on earth do you want another ViewModel to evaluate something for your current ViewModel ?

Comment: I want to read combo-box and check box values from Control R from within VM_MAIN.

Comment: Either view model A has to have a reference to the view model B and call a method or invoked a command of it or both view models can communicate with each other using a messenger. What other option are you looking for? It's either this or merge the two view models into one.

Comment: @mm8 I have considered this option, how ever the messenger is one way communication. Is there a two way Messenger ?

Comment: No. That would defeat the purpose of using a messenger...a view model just publishes a message to the messenger and doesn't care about what happens with it. That's what the pattern is all about.

Comment: @mm8 That takes me back to my original option 2. Create to register calls and two send calls in the two view models. Is this the best way of doing it ?

Comment: Reusable WPF controls typically don't have a view model at all. A common error made when creating a UserControl is to explicitly set its DataContext to an instance of its "own" view model. Doing so effectively prevents that the control inherits a DataContext from its parent, and usually breaks Bindings to its properties.

Comment: If view model A expects a result from view model B you might as well use a direct reference to view model B because then they are in fact indirectly coupled to each other anyway. If view model A cannot work properly without getting a result back from view model B it does indeed have a dependency upon the latter.

Comment: Your "coupling concerns" are unfounded. You already have the Views coupled, MainVM owning a VM_R is quite OK.

Comment: I feel like this stems from a design issue. @John, are you opposed to changing around your relations? versus 2 choices that cause massive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing a reusable WPF control "R" that has its own view model "VM_R".

That's probably wrong. Generally speaking, if you think you need a view-model for a particular control, what you are really doing is putting the code in the wrong place.

Stick that stuff into the code-behind for the control and expose dependency properties that the real model or view-model can bind to.

> Instantiate VM_R in VM_Main. This will create a coupling concerns.

That confirms my suspicion that you are putting the code in the wrong place.

> I can use MVVM Light Messenger.

No. Don't ever use that. MVVM Light Messenger is just a massive memory leak waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest to go with option 1, but in some better way. You can make use DI to inject R_VM to R_Main. Here is example

```
public interface IR_VM
{
    int MyMethod(int param);
}

public class R_VM : IR_VM
{
    public int MyMethod(int param)
    {
        // implemention
        return 0;
    }
}

public class VM_Main
{
    public VM_Main(IR_VM rvm)
    {
        RVM = rvm;
    }
    public IR_VM RVM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that creating interfaces for ViewModels does not improve your code quality. It is kind of like a workaround "to not have a direct reference". If a view contains another view, the ViewModel can have a direct reference.

Comment: You haven't removed any coupling, you've just make it more complicated to instantiate VM_Main. Oh, and harder to debug by adding a layer of indirection.

Comment: There is no coupling at all. Here I am injecting vm, not having direct reference. If you finding this hard then I will suggest to read about DI first. Probably that will help to understand my approach.